# Closure and interior of topology

Tags: general-topology

1) $cl(\mathbb R) $

2) $int ([1, \infty) \cup $ {3})

3) $ \partial (-1,\infty ) \cap $ {-3} 
 it’s a boundary

My solution: 
1)  it’s same $\mathbb R $
2) $(1,\infty ) \cap $ {3}
3)  {-1,-3}
Correct or no ?

Comment: Recall that the closure of a set $A$ is the smallest closed subset containing $A$ and the interior of $A$ is the largest open subset contained in $A$. Moreover, the boundary of $A$ is the closure without the interior of $A$. Therefore, 1 is correct, 2 is not correct and 3: should that be the intersection or union?

Answer (score 2):

1. Correct: it is $\mathbb R$.
2. Correct, but why didn't you just write that the interior is $(-1,\infty)$?
3. Wrong. Since $\partial(-1,\infty)=\{-1\}$, $\bigl(\partial(-1,\infty)\bigr)\cap\{3\}=\emptyset$. Unless you meant $\partial\bigl((-1,\infty)\cap\{3\}\bigr)$, in which case the answer is $\{3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

In case 2) why do you write that the interior is the intersection of interiors?  This may lead you to false  , if for example instead of $3$ were $-2$.